# python 2.5.2 crashes with basic use of threading

Tags: python, multithreading, crash

I'm working on a program that needs some threading. I wanted to get myself into this and tried several tutorials. Because of some special hardware I need to stick to Python 2.5.2 (r25:51908)

When I want to run the following code

```
import threading

class PrintThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        print "foobar"

thread = PrintThread()
thread.start()
```

I get the famous error "pythonw.exe has encountered a problem ...". This only happens on my PC. When I tried the very same code on a differenct PC with the same installation of Python (also with the same additional libraries like visa), it just works!

I uninstalled Python and reinstalled it again, but the error is still occuring. Any suggestions?

Comment: I had this same problem, and it seemed to come from anytime the script was run from a `.pyw` instead of a regular one.

Comment: Well, this script is called threading.py, and I start it from IDLE via the F5-key. Sorry, but what does your comment mean to me -- practically?

Comment: `import threading` in a script with the filename `threading.py` is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: Just for testing purposes :-) But this doesn't change anything about my problem.

Comment: Have you tried it without calling the script threading.py, this is guaranteed to cause a crash!

Comment: Yes, I've tried, as I mentioned above. Python still crashes.